# How can I use a namespace from ASP.Net 5 MVC preview template project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

In Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 I have two projects: the first is created on the basis of ASP.NET 5 Preview templates (Web Application), the second is Unit Test project. In order to test some methods in the first project, I want to add a reference to it in my TestProject. However, I get an error "A reference to "MVCProject" could not be added". How can I resolve this problem?

UPD: Target platform for TestProject is .NET 4.5.2 (I tried also swith to .NET 4.6, didn't get any difference in terms of my question). In MVCProject I find only the following info: Solution DNX SDK Version: Version=1.0.0 beta5, Platform= .NET Framework, Architecture=x86 - and that's all.

Comment: Check the target platform and framework of the unit test project, ensure they match

Comment: updated my question to meet your answer

Comment: Probably stupid question from me, are these two projects in the same solution?

Comment: to Rosdi Kasim: yes, they are in the same solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for asp.net 5 you should not add "Test Projects", instead you add a class library package project for testing with xunit. [this article should help you](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html)

then you should have no problem adding a reference

Comment: Thank you, this resolved this very problem, I've managed to reach needed namespaces from my project supposed to be a test-project.